# Shell script pass arguments to another shell script

Tags: python, bash, shell

I'm writing a shell script that calls another shell script which calls a python script, and passes an argument throughout the whole chain like so:

Directory structure:

```
first
scripts
  |- second
  |- third
```

first

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

date=$1
p=$2

(cd ./scripts/ && ./second "$p")
```

second

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function myFunction() {
    ./third $1
}
myFunction
```

third

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

p = sys.argv[1]
print("I got " + p)
```

I know it's a mess, but I need this to work in this way for now.

When I try `./first 20180716 0.5`

I expect this code to print "I got 0.5", but the python script seems to complain:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./third", line 4, in <module>
    p = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Which means that nothing seems to be passing to ./third. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried to reproduce this exactly as posted and it worked fine. Can you please double check by copy-pasting from your post into files in a new directory and rerunning the experiment? (specifically, avoid copying your existing files in case they're slightly different from your post)

Comment: It worked for me as well

Comment: I also tried it just as you described and it worked for me. Seems like it may be an environment thing. It might be best to write a script that calls each of them and passes the results from one to the next.

Comment: Note that quotes matter, btw. `second "$2"` and `./third "$1"` will have fewer issues when your arguments have spaces.

Comment: I added more detail

Comment: I'd also suggest enabling logging for all your shell scripts; add `set -x` as a line immediately after the shebang, and you'll be able to see where things first go wrong.

Comment: `./third "$1"`, by the way, will ensure that there's **always** an argument passed to `third`, even if that argument is an empty string -- whereas right now, passing an empty string (or a string containing only characters in `IFS`) into `second` results in no arguments being passed to `third`.

Comment: ...that said, this still has yet to be reproduced by anyone but you. Could you create a single script that sets up the entire structure in question and runs it, thus being a simple copy/paste to fully reproduce the issue?

Comment: I've provided an attempt at a reproducer that *doesn't* actually reproduce the problem. If you can edit it into a reproducer that *does* create the problem, amend that into the question, someone other than you might be able to see the issue. :)

Comment: So I think figured it out. In `second`, I was making the call to `third` in a function. So I was probably sending the `$1` of the parameterless function to `third` instead of the `$1` of the whole `second` script.

Answer (score 1):

As an attempted reproducer (which will be deleted as soon as the question is edited with a MCVE):

```
# create a temporary directory
tempdir=$(mktemp -d "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/repro.XXXXXX") || exit

# create our "first" script
cat >"$tempdir/first" <<'EOF'
#!/usr/bin/env bash

date=$1
p=$2

(cd ./scripts/ && ./second "$p")
EOF

# create a "scripts" directory    
mkdir "$tempdir/scripts" || exit

# create our "second" script
cat >"$tempdir/scripts/second" <<'EOF'
#!/usr/bin/env bash

./third $1
EOF

# create our "third" script
cat >"$tempdir/scripts/third" <<'EOF'
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

p = sys.argv[1]
print("I got " + p)
EOF

chmod +x "$tempdir"/{first,scripts/{second,third}}  # make the scripts all executable...
cd "$tempdir" && ./first 20180716 0.5               # and actually run the first one
```

...properly emits `0.5`.